# Using values from SQL table in a Google Static Maps request

Tags: php, sql-server, google-maps-static-api

I need to create multiple Static Maps on my page (suppliers.php), and the latitude and longitude co-ordinates are requested from my SQL table "suppliers". As I have multiple maps, I wanted to concatenate the variables into the image source but I get the following error:

"Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\suppliers.php on line 73".

*Here are lines 71, 72 and 73.*

```
$latitude = $row["latitude"];
$longitude = $row.["longitude"];
$map = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&zoom=13&size=300x300&key=[my key]";
```

Is it possible for me to create the multiple maps or not?

Comment: there is a dot in your second line, thats creating the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hot a typo in the second line, `$row.["longitude"]` should be `$row["longitude"]`.

Your notice says that your are impliciting doing an array to string conversion, that's because `$row.["longitude"]` returns two arrays, `$row` and an array containing only `longitude` as a string.

Comment: Argh, must be very annoying to have to answer such stupid questions. Thank you so much!!